# How to get customer reviews from yelp in R

Tags: html, xml, r

I am trying to get customer reviews from yelp. but i do not know how to locate the review in xpath in r.
my code right now is like

```
url<-'http://www.yelp.com/biz/cheese-board-pizza-berkeley'
doc<-htmlParse(url)
xpathSApply(doc,'//div[@p class="review_comment ieSucks"]',xmlValue)
```

can someone help me with the xpath in r?

thank you!

Comment: Yelp has an [API](http://www.yelp.ca/developers/documentation) that allows you to get data as `json`. You will need to register for an API key, and use a package like `httr` to query the API.

Comment: but do u know how to do this with R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
urll <- 'http://www.yelp.com/biz/cheese-board-pizza-berkeley'
library(XML)
doc <- htmlParse(urll)
xpathSApply(doc,'//p[@class="review_comment ieSucks"]', xmlValue, encoding="UTF-8")
```

I suggest you to try [xPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/) for Firefox or something similar.

Comment: thank you so much!. do you have any good reference for me to learn about xpath?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I just began exploring them, too. But SO and other sites are full of examples. This + the reference + tools like the suggested one should be a good starting point.

Comment: it helps me a lot. i learnt it before. cuz it is kind of trivial, i forgot most of it now. =)